# How to pass an image src into a modal dialog in Vue (in order to zoom the clicked image)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

What I'm trying to do is to zoom an image on click, the idea is:

- you click on an image
- dialog of `width=85vw` opens up with the image you just clicked on inside of it (so the image is displayed almost fullscreen now)

I cannot think of a better way of "zooming" an image on click, but to open it in a modal dialog (if there's an easier way, please let me know).

### Code:

```html
 <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="85vw" >
     <img :src="img1" alt="" width="100%" @click.stop="dialog=false">
 </v-dialog>
                
 <img :src="img1" width="500px"  @click.stop="dialog = true">
 <img :src="img2" width="500px"  @click.stop="dialog = true">
 <img :src="img3" width="500px"  @click.stop="dialog = true">
```

```js
 export default {
     data() {
         img1: "../../src/assets/pexels-photo-373912.jpg",
         img2: "../../src/assets/pexels-photo-373912.jpg",
         img3: "../../src/assets/pexels-photo-373912.jpg"
     }
 }
```

The problem is, it's not opening any clicked image in a dialog, just the one you hard coded in there, in this example it will always open `img1` no matter what image you click.

I don't know how to pass the `:src` into the dialog dynamically - the `:src` of the image you clicked.

*P.S. v-dialog is a component from Vuetify.js library*

---

#### Question:

- Is there an obviously better way of doing it?
- If not really, how do I make this method to work and display the image I clicked in the modal dialog?

Comment: How about when you click on an image, it gets the `zoomed` class added to it, which is styled `position: fixed` with the size you want it?

Comment: @RoyJ that's a good idea, though a class with `position: fixed` makes the image disappear for some reason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a variable to hold which image is selected. When you click on an image, it should set the variable to the url for that image. When you click on the dialog image, it should unset the variable.

The dialog should show when the variable is set and otherwise be hidden.

For simplicity, I'm not using an actual dialog, just a div. It looks like you would use it for the dialog's `v-model` rather than using the `v-if` I use.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedImage: null,
    images: [
      'http://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=image%201',
      'http://via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=image%202',
      'http://via.placeholder.com/500x500?text=image%203'
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    zoom(url) {
      console.log("Zoom", url);
      this.selectedImage = url;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="selectedImage" max-width="85vw">
    <img :src="selectedImage" alt="" width="100%" @click.stop="selectedImage = null">
    <hr>
  </div>

  <div v-for="url in images">
    <img :src="url" width="100px" @click="zoom(url)">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have a problem with it though. You see, the images are distributed across the page in different elements, so I can't just use one `<img>` in a loop to display them in one place. I'm not sure how to apply this method in this case

Comment: Is there a way to do something like this directly on an image to just pass the src of this image into the function?:

`<img src="/image1.jpg"  @click="zoom(this, src)">`

Comment: I figured I can just do it like this below, but I have to always specify src in 2 places:

`<img src="/image1.jpg" @click="zoom('/image1.jpg')">`  Do you happen to know if there's a way to pass the `src` attribute of the element into a function like in the comment above?

Comment: If you don't pass an argument, `zoom` will get the Event object, and you can use `event.target.src`

Comment: Sweet, it works. Thank you very much, your answers were very helpful!

Comment: can you guide me how to open the bigger image in a dialog box in vue js

Comment: @BhavinKalal That sounds like a couple of issues. Start by looking at this example. https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html

Answer (score 1):

to click distributed images across the page define a property and change it with click event

in template

```
 <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="60%" @keydown.esc="cancel">
      <v-card>
        <v-img :src="pic" alt="" contain/>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  <v-img
      src="require(@/assets/clinic/1.jpeg)"
      alt=""
      contain
      @click="openPic(require('@/assets/clinic/1.jpeg'))"//this part is important you have to require image
   />
```

in script

```
data() {
    return {
      pic: "",
      dialog: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openPic(image) {
      this.dialog = true
      this.pic = image
    },
    cancel() {
      this.dialog = false
    }
  }
```